# Markdown2 text rendering as a string using Python and Django

Tags: python, django, markdown

I'm working on a project that takes in a markdown page and converts it into HTML before inserting it into the correct document. This is the code I'm running

Python

```
def markdown(request, entry):
pathOfFile = "entries/" + entry + ".md"
return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
    "html_markdown": markdown2.markdown_path(pathOfFile)
})
```

HTML

```
{% block body %}
<div>
    {{ html_markdown }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is what is returning on the web page

```
<h1>CSS</h1> <p>CSS is a language that can be used to add style to an <a href="/wiki/HTML">HTML</a> page.</p>
```

When I inspect the source of the page the HTML is encased in quotes. Is the problem that my html_markdown variable is being read as a string? What steps can I take to get the HTML to render properly? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`html_markdown` will contain *raw* HTML, so if you render that in the template, it will *escape* characters like `<` to `&lt;`, etc.

You can mark the string as "safe" with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to prevent escaping these characters:

```
{% block body %}
<div>
    {{ html_markdown|safe }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```